# Expect that a certain function is called

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have an `onChange` listener and I want to make sure that the listener gets called.

I do actually have code that woks but it seems weird.

```js
test('on change should be invoked when deleting', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    someTestThing.onChange.sub(() => expect(true).toBe(true));
    await someTestThing.delete(TEST_ID);
});
```

I'm referring to the `expect(true).toBe(true)` part not seeming right.

### Edit:

I guess I could also do this, which does seem a bit more reasonable, actually I quite like it:

```js
test('on change should be invoked when deleting', async () => {
    const cb = jest.fn();
    someTestThing.onChange.sub(cb);
    await someTestThing.delete(TEST_ID);
    expect(cb.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jest’s `toHaveBeenCalled` assertion.

```
const someTestThing = {
  onChange: (event: Event) => console.log(event),
  delete: async (id: string) => console.log(id)
}

it('on change should be invoked when deleting', async () => {
  const mock = jest.fn(someTestThing.onChange);

  mock(new CustomEvent('Foo'));
  await someTestThing.delete('1')

  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

[Documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions)

Comment: I mean I see what you're saying, but you're calling the bock manually here, of course it will be called.